# ALSA: Full duplex C example?

Tags: c, linux, alsa

is there an example of a full-duplex ALSA connection in C? I've read that it is supported, but all the introductory examples I saw did either record or play a sound sample, but I'd like to have one handler that can do both for my VoIP-app.

Big thanks for help,
Jens

Comment: +1 because I'd like to know the answer too. I'd also be interested in knowing, if you use the OSS api for an ALSA device, whether opening it `O_RDWR` is sufficient to get full duplex, or if you need to use the ugly old-style OSS full-duplex setup `ioctl` stuff, or if it even works at all...

Comment: I write an answer to this question at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/504526/235261 an attempt to provide a full duplex alsa.

Answer (score 6):

Some guy named Alan has published this good (but old) tutorial, [Full Duplex ALSA](http://www.saunalahti.fi/~s7l/blog/2005/08/21/Full%20Duplex%20ALSA), which is written in C.

Answer (score 3):

You provide a link to both handles and pump them in turn.
Here's alan's code elided and commented.

```
// the device plughw handle dynamic sample rate and type conversion.
// there are a range of alternate devices defined in your alsa.conf
// try: 
// locate alsa.conf
// and check out what devices you have in there
//  
// The following device is PLUG:HW:Device:0:Subdevice:0
// Often simply plug, plughw, plughw:0, will have the same effect 
//
char           *snd_device_in  = "plughw:0,0";
char           *snd_device_out = "plughw:0,0";

// handle constructs to populate with our links
snd_pcm_t      *playback_handle;
snd_pcm_t      *capture_handle;

//this is the usual construct... If not fail BLAH
if ((err = snd_pcm_open(&playback_handle, snd_device_out, SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0)) < 0) {
fprintf(stderr, "cannot open output audio device %s: %s\n", snd_device_in, snd_strerror(err));
exit(1);
}

// And now the CAPTURE
if ((err = snd_pcm_open(&capture_handle, snd_device_in, SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0)) < 0) {
fprintf(stderr, "cannot open input audio device %s: %s\n", snd_device_out, snd_strerror(err));
exit(1);
}
```

then config and pump them.

A ring mod could do the job: http://soundprogramming.net/programming_and_apis/creating_a_ring_buffer or you could use alans way outlined above.

Comment: A FIFO-stack with some predetermined item-limit would be simpler and safer than a ring-buffer.

Answer (score 3):

It was my first requirements to a Linux/Unix VoIP projects where I need to know about all of the available audio devices capability and name. Then I need to use these devices to capture and playback the audio.

For everyone's help I have made a (.so) library and a sample Application demonstrating the use of this library in c++.

The output of my library is like-

```
[root@~]# ./IdeaAudioEngineTest
HDA Intel plughw:0,0
HDA Intel plughw:0,2
USB Audio Device plughw:1,0
```

The library provides functionality to capture and playback real-time audio data.

Full source with documentation is available in [IdeaAudio library with Duplex Alsa Audio](http://matrixsust.blogspot.com/2013/07/ideaaudio-library-with-duplex-alsa.html)

Library source is now open at [github.com](https://github.com/robelsharma/IdeaAudio)

Answer (score 2):

See also `latency.c`, included in `alsa-lib` source; on the ALSA wiki:

- http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Test_latency.c

Comment: don't understand the downvote - the example you link is supposed to utilize full-duplex acc. to it's documentation